# With Sails.js how can I make /users/me a route that works with associations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a main model `Accounts`, then I have a few `Has Many` models like `Notifications` and `Friends`

In my `main.js`

I'd like to be able to do things like:

`socket.get('/users/me/notifications');`

instead of like:

`socket.get('/users/ + g_userAccountId + '/notifications');`

^^ That works for right now, but it is set asynchronously so if any code loads before `g_userAccountId` is set it will try to use `undefined` instead which is bad.. Very bad..

I understand policies and all that I'm just wondering how I can make this work with the REST blueprints and what not. If I'm not clear please let me know

Is there a way to do this without setting `findOne` methods in each controller? Like to automatically fill in `/me/` with `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can imagine doing this without setting findOne methods in each controller would be to create a policy that matches the `/users/me/notifications` route, redirecting it to the current session's user id. You could potentially use something like the following, and update the `/config/policy` file.

```
if (session.authenticated) {
    return res.redirect('/users/' + req.session.user.id + '/notifications');
}
```

If you wanted to do something to handle anytime the `/users/me` route is hit, you could modify this policy, tweak the req.url and redirect to the new one that uses the user ID, and apply it to all relevant routes in policy config file, or setup a [custom middleware](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Middleware) to handle the problem the same way.